# Задача на комбинаторику(кодовый замок)

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Кодовый замок имеет 8 одинаковых ячеек, каждую из которых можно
установить в 26 устойчивых положений (10 цифр, 16 букв). сколько различных
комбинаций необходимо перебрать, чтобы не зная кода открыть замок, если 5 первых позиций цифры, другие -литеры

Comment: Перепишите свой вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: Скоро уже с таблицей умножения начнут приходить. Как умножить 7 на 8.

Comment: @Эникейщик На мете такие вопросы - чему равно 2+2 - признаны очень важными и полезными... https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/195342

Comment: @Harry этот, на мой взгляд, попадает под "Составные вопросы с элементарной задачей без попыток её решить" из главы "бесполезные вопросы".

Answer (score 1):

Все предельно просто - первая позиция - 10 вариантов, вторая - 10, ... пятая - 10, итого 100000 вариантов.

Для трех последних каждая позиция может иметь 16 вариантов, итого 16*16*16=4096.

Значит, весь замок может иметь 409600000 вариантов.

А сколько перебрать? С точки зрения матстатистики :) в среднем - половину всего количества вариантов. Ну, а что именно от вас хотят в такой странной формулировке - дело другое...

Comment: сколько различных комбинаций необходимо перебрать если 5 первых позиций цифры, другие -литеры?

Comment: @rootuser вам же вроде сказали. 100000 вариантов для первых пяти позиций, если там могут быть только цифры. И 4096 вариантов для последних трёх позиций, если там могут быть только литеры. Умножаете, получаете всего 409600000 вариантов.

А вообще в целом у этого замка может быть 208827064576 комбинаций.

Comment: Вы ответы читаете или вы только писать горазды?... "Чукча не читатель, чукча писатель" :(